# Syntax error when using SS_REALSIZECONTROL in picture control

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, win32gui

I am making a dialog based win32 gui application. I am basically making a gui to operate AVL tree. This is the look of the application:

[image]

I have a picture control to display a bitmap which is generated from .gv file consisting of dot language to display a graph. The bitmap is being generated as it should.

In my resource.rc file, this is my picture control definition

```
CONTROL "", ID_PIC, WC_STATIC, WS_BORDER | SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTERIMAGE, 165, 30, 410, 218, WS_EX_LEFT
```

And this is the view when bitmap loads in the picture control:

[image]

The bitmap is correct but it is being cropped, I want the picture control to fully display the bitmap. What should I do?

I also tried to use `SS_REALSIZECONTROL`, but it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: The picture control is under the static text "CURRENT VIEW OF AVL TREE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct usage for `SS_REALSIZECONTROL` is as follows:

```
CONTROL IDB_BITMAP1,IDC_X,"Static",SS_BITMAP|SS_CENTERIMAGE|SS_REALSIZECONTROL|WS_BORDER,136,7,121,145
```

This will shrink the bitmap if necessary and center it in the middle of static control.

`SS_REALSIZECONTROL` requires at least Windows XP target, it is defined as

```
#if(WINVER >= 0x0501)
#define SS_REALSIZECONTROL  0x00000040L
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0501 */
```

If you are not using newer versions of Visual Studio you may need to declare `WINVER >= 0x0501` or use the constant value `0x00000040L`